# Extreme Forgetfulness and Concentration Issue During Salah

Tags: salat, waswasa

Assalmu Alaykum.

I forget everything during a prayer. No matter how hard I try I cannot remember whether I have recited the Surah Al Fatiha, whether I have done the ruqu, or how many sizdah I have done during a raqat, or whether I have sat for the first tashahood. I sometimes also forget how many raqats I have prayed, though usually, I have inherent feelings about how many raqats I have prayed. It happens to me during almost every prayer and almost every raqat. And I try so hard to remember and not to forget which steps I have done I forget it right away. **I usually don't forget to do these steps, but I completely forget whether I have done them or not.**

I sometimes redo the prayer once twice and sometimes even more, I sometimes add a raqat at the end of the prayer and do the prostration of forgetfulness as I have read somewhere that if I forget a pillar of a salat, I will have to repeat the raqat, which is also vey hard for me.

Please advise me as to what to do in these cases, should I repeat salat or maybe I can just ignore them and continue with my prayer?

As a side note, in other prayers or in worldly tasks, I am not forgetful to this extent. However, I have a severe concentration issue, no matter how hard I try I cannot concentrate much on tasks like reading a book or an article, including the recitation of the Holy Quran.